# How can I tell if Gnome-Boxes is using KVM?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, gnome-boxes

I'm using `gnome-boxes` to run lubuntu inside a virtual machine. I am wondering how I can verify whether or not it is using KVM? I am using a CPU that supports virtualization (Intel Core i5 3330) and kvm is enabled in the kernel. However, I don't see any clear indication in the `gnome-boxes` preferences panel for the VM that confirms one way or another if it is using KVM.

Answer (score 3):

According to [What is the technology used by Boxes?](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/supported-protocols.html.en):

> Boxes uses qemu-kvm, libvirt-glib and spice-gtk to allow users to easily manage virtual machines and connect to remote machines.
>
> ... QEMU achieves near native performance by executing the guest code directly on the host CPU using KVM.
>
> KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a Linux kernel module that allows a user space program to use the hardware virtualization features of various processors.

I ran `apt install -s gnome-boxes` within a VM of Kubuntu 20.04. Here's a partial output on that system. (The packages to be installed on your system may differ depending on what you already have):

> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   cpu-checker dmeventd **gnome-boxes** ibverbs-providers ipxe-qemu 
>   ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms libaio1 libbrlapi0.7 libcacard0
>   libcue2 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libexempi8 libfdt1 libgexiv2-2
>   libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgvnc-1.0-0 
>   libgxps2 libibverbs1 libiscsi7 liblvm2cmd2.03 libosinfo-1.0-0
>   libosinfo-bin libphodav-2.0-0 libphodav-2.0-common libpmem1
>   libpoppler-glib8 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libreadline5
>   libslirp0 libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 
>   libspice-server1 libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser18 
>   libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 
>   libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libusbredirhost1 libusbredirparser1 
>   libvirglrenderer1 libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu
>   libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd libvirt-glib-1.0-0 libvirt0 
>   libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common lvm2 msr-tools osinfo-db ovmf
>   qemu-block-extra **qemu-kvm** qemu-system-common qemu-system-data 
>   qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils seabios sharutils 
>   spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper thin-provisioning-tools tracker
>   tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
>   0 upgraded, 69 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

As you can see, KVM is part of gnome-boxes (`qemu-kvm` is bolded in the output). If your kernel doesn't support KVM, `gnome-boxes` won't run. I had an older laptop which could run VirtualBox but not KVM because it failed `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`.

If you want to check further, run `pgrep qemu` without GNOME Boxes running and with GNOME Boxes running. Examine the (lengthy) command being executed in the latter case.

According to [this video titled "GNOME Boxes: Virtualization made simple …](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRjY2plEymQ) from March 2020, *Felipe Borges* is currently largely responsible for GNOME Boxes. I guess he could authoritatively answer the question of whether GNOME Boxes uses or doesn't use KVM.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So, you're saying that Boxes will always use KVM, if it is available? Hmm ... I think what I am really after though is some way to verify *for sure* that a running Boxes VM is using KVM. Presumably, Boxes can run on a machine that doesn't have it?

Comment: No, kvm is part of gnome-boxes. If your kernel doesn't support kvm, gnome-boxes won't run. I had an older laptop which could run VirtualBox but not kvm.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. It might be worth adding that to your answer, that Gnome Boxes won't work without KVM.

Comment: Modified. Let me know if you need further clarification.